# Slow SSD in usb 3.0 external case when booting linux toram

Tags: linux, boot, live-usb

I have installed a squashfs, needed for the `toram` option, on an `ext4` partition. The partition is on a SSD in an external case.

The SSD is said to have a speed up to 500 MB/s for reading.

When I run `hdparm -t /dev/sdb` it says the read speed of the SSD is arround 370 MB/s.

But when I boot the `toram` linux, having disabled the splash screen in kernel parameters, and launching the kernel with the parameter `toram=filesystem.squashfs`, I can see the loading speed of the squashfs into RAM. The speed is only from 130 MB/s to 150 MB/s.

So I wonder if there is a way to make the kernel load the squashfs faster ?

EDIT:

Here is the `lsusb` output, the enclosure is the Device 009 on Bus 002:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0415 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 2-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5415 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 2-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 145f:02c9 Trust Trust Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The `lsusb -t` output:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/7p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 480M
```

And the beginning of `lsusb -v -s 002:009` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x152d JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x0578 JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s
  bcdDevice           25.01
  iManufacturer           1 JMicron
  iProduct                2 External HDD
  iSerial                 3 0000007788E1
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reads and Writes Over USB

The bottleneck you see isn't from the SSD.  The bottleneck comes from the limited transfer speeds of the USB connection. Once added to the external enclosure, the SSD becomes a glorified USB Flash Drive.

The Specification for USB 3.0 (which I attempted to read through, but could not find where the speeds were buried), and could only verify through [multiple links/search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%203.0%20flash%20drive%20read%2Fwrite%20speed&sca_esv=0573b43c5c641ce9&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS1055US1055&sxsrf=ACQVn08pXp4nme3g9jEbCrzYnl3bT3Ta2A%3A1707929346023&ei=Au_MZYV2-quq2w-aro2wDA&oq=usb%20read%20speed&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiDnVzYiByZWFkIHNwZWVkKgIIADIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwAzIKEAAYRxjWBBiwA0iGGlAAWABwAXgAkAEAmAGaAaABmgGqAQMwLjG4AQHIAQDiAwQYACBBiAYBkAYI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) was:

> For USB 3.0 technology, the average read speed range jumps up to 60 to 150 Mbps. As for write speeds, you can expect a range of 10 to 45 Mbps with a USB 3.0 unit.

Note the above quote is stated as the **average throughput**.

The `hdparm` command is returning the rated speed inside the enclosure, i.e the speed between the adapter that the drive is connected to and the drive itself, Since the enclosure mimics a connection inside the PC, this makes sense.  The connection adapter may only be rated for a certain speed also, but I can only verify that  if you update your original question with a link to the enclosure.

### In Response to Comments

[Clearing Up the Confusion About USB... Again](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/computers/tips-and-solutions/clearing-up-the-confusion-about-usb-again) states:

> ... can be backward-compatible with older devices, although they will be limited to the older USB standard’s data transfer rate.

I left speeds out of that quote because the backwards compatibility applies too all speeds and generations.  Also note that 3.2 Gen 2 SuperSpeed is not the same as 3.2 [What is USB 3.0 (SuperSpeed USB)?](https://www.techtarget.com/searchwindowsserver/definition/USB-30-SuperSpeed-USB#:%7E:text=USB%203.0%20is%20a%20Universal,also%20known%20as%20SuperSpeed%20USB.) also states:

> The USB 3.2 standard was introduced in July 2017. The USB 3.2 standard includes a new transfer mode of 20 Gbps that works with USB-C connectors. It is known as SuperSpeed+ or USB Gen 2x2. The 3.2 standard also renamed the older transfer speeds.
>
> Because of the somewhat complicated naming, new USB 3.0 devices should include the maximum supported transfer speed in the device logo. Fortunately all USB data transfer rate standards are backwards compatible, meaning that almost any device can be used with any plug, and it will automatically fall back to the best mutually supported speed.

The OP is expecting here that the maximum stated in the specifications should be the *guaranteed throughput*, which will **never be true**, due to differences in device manufacturing, OS configuration etc.

### Update

After reading through multiple posts turned up by Google, it seems that the JMicron microchip line that drives that enclosure is unreliable. See [this post over on the Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=322899) for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` possible fix and replace the DeviceID with `152d:0578`

Comment: USB 3.0 support a speed of 5 Gb/s, so approximately 500 MB/s. I also have seen some manufacturers selling usb flash drives, standard 3.2 Gen 2x1 (10 Gb/s), with a read speed up to 1000 MB/s and a write speed up to 800 MB/s.

Comment: That's `3.0/3.2 SuperSpeed` not plain 3.0.  Your enclosure is probably "plain 3.0"

Comment: Adding: Even if the enclosure is marketed at `3.0 SuperSpeed` your connected device/PC must have a port of the same type.  If you connect a SuperSpeed Rated device to a plain 3.0 port both sides negotiate at the 3.0 speeds.  The same happens when you connect a 3.x rated device to a 2.0 port, you get 2.0 speeds.  That's why the port plugs are different colors.  If both sides are Blue you'll have a true 3.0 connection

Comment: I have tested my enclosure, said for 5 Gb/s by the manufacturer, on another computer, and it loads the squashfs at arround 370 MB/s. So I think the problem comes from my computer hardware or from the usb linux driver for its usb controller. Despite this computer specifications said "USB 3.2 Gen 2".

Comment: @Bertrand125: In that case, let's make sure the right driver is in use.  Please add the output of `lsusb` to your question, with the drive in the enclosure and whether the USB Plug is White or Blue on the PC.

Comment: I have added the output of `lsusb` command to my question.

Comment: I've added a possible fix in the Update Section.  If that, doesn't fix it, we're out of options as the microchip that drives the transfer rates is unreliable.  Google search for: `152d:0578 linux driver issues` to see what I mean.